# Trying to std::move on std::unique_ptr holding FILE ptr and passing it to struct constructor

Tags: c++, std, move, unique-ptr

I'm following the book "C++ Crash Course" by J.Lospinoso, and I'm currently on Chapter 11 presenting smart pointers.

In the first exercise, the reader has to edit the below code with file handling when using `std::unique_ptr`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using FileGuard = std::unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)>;

void say_hello(FileGuard file){
    fprintf(file.get(), "HELLO DAVE");
}

int main() {

    auto file = fopen("HAL9000", "w");
    if(!file) return errno;
    FileGuard file_guard{ file, fclose };
    //File open here
    say_hello(std::move (file_guard));
    //File closed here
    return 0;
}
```

The case is to change `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr`.

After this, we can pass `file_guard` to the `say_hello()` function without `std::move()`, and make more calls to `say_hello()`, everything works fine.

In the next exercise, the reader has to write a class like below, it's already a little bit modified:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using FileGuard = std::shared_ptr<FILE>;

struct Hal {
    Hal(std::shared_ptr<FILE> file):file(file){}
    ~Hal(){
        fprintf(file.get(), "Stop, Dave\n");
    }
    void write_status(const char* ch, int len){
        fprintf(file.get(), ch);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<FILE> file;
};

int main() {
    
    auto file = fopen("HAL9000", "w");
    if(!file) return errno;
    //{
    FileGuard file_guard{ file, fclose};
    Hal hal1{std::move(file_guard)};
    hal1.write_status("I'm completely operational1\n", 8);
    if (file) std::cout<<"File is not closed\n";
    //} 
    fprintf(file, "I can still write after std::move..\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, why can I still write to the file line `"I can still write after std::move..\n"` if I have moved `file_guard` to the `Hal` object? Is it overall correct syntax?

When uncommenting the braces in `main()` to create scope, I don't have access to the file anymore, because as I hope `fclose()` is invoked when `hal1` object is destructed, isn't it?

I know there is lot of C, but this is how the book is written, at least to some place.

Compiling on Windows 11 with MSVC 19.33.31629.

---

**EDIT**:

```cpp
int main() {
    
    auto file = fopen("HAL9000", "w");
    if(!file) return errno;
    FileGuard file_guard{std::move(file), fclose};
    {
    Hal hal1{file_guard}; //adding std::move causing undef behaviour? Nothing saved to file anyway.
    hal1.write_status("I'm completely operational1\n", 8);
    }
    Hal hal2{file_guard};
    hal2.write_status("I'm completely operational2\n", 8);
    fprintf(file, "I can still write after std::move..\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_fclose is invoked when hal1 object is destructed, isn't it?_": Yes, exactly. And considering where `hal1` is destroyed without the braces, I am not sure why you are surprised that `file` can still be used in the last line.

Comment: You can even use a more generic pattern : scope guard, which allows you to call a lambda in case of any exit from the function. And this lambda could close the file for you. But in this case why not refactor to std::ifstream (and get rid of the old "C" style FILE pointer)

Comment: `file` is a raw pointer. You assign a value to it, which never changes even if the file is closed elsewhere. You should not use `file` directly, always go via a `FileGuard` object.

Comment: @user17732522, @rustyx Thank you for your answers, I played around with both examples and indeed I get it now. However, can you tell me what is wrong with my thinking when looking at the code under //EDIT1 please? `std::move` for the `file_guard` has of course consequences but when running it on the `file` there is no effect? All lines are written to the file.
@Pepijn Kramer thank you, I'm just following the course and I believe I won't use those examples in real life, but do you think it is possible to recreate the one with `Hal` class and `shared_ptr` but using `std::fsteam`?

Comment: You should not use the variable `file` after creating the FileGuard.  In particular, `file` will still hold a value (it is a simple FILE*) even after the FileGuard has expired and the file is closed.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy sure, I'm aware of it, I'm just trying to get know how the things work in the background, from curiosity and for safety too.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you `move` into the argument of `say_hello`, but it is the `}` at the end of `say_hello` that triggers the destructor of the file guard to run and close the file, not the `move`.

Likewise, the line

```
Hal hal1{std::move(file_guard)};
```

does not cause the destructor of `file_guard` to run nor does it close the file any other way. The file is kept open at long as there is a `shared_ptr` alive that points to file. Move constructing one shared pointer from another does not change the reference count of the pointed-to object and therefore will never run the destructor of the pointed-to object. It is only when the destructor of `hal1` runs  at the end of main that the `shared_ptr` it owns gets destructed and closes the file, so the file is still open at the time of your `fprintf`.

If you uncomment those curly braces, the destructor of `hal1` will run at the closing `}`. Calling `fprintf` on a closed file is undefined behavior and as such the program is undefined and what actually happens depends on your compiler.

Comment: @273K Use of the `FILE*` pointer value after `fclose` in any way is UB according to both C and POSIX, it becomes an invalid/indeterminate pointer value. See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fclose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just to be clear, like @273K wrote, I'm not getting undefined behavior when uncommenting braces so scope is present, just `fprintf` doesn't write that line to the file.

Comment: @273K Giving references for what the previous user mentioned, C++ standard (29.12.1) defines the contents of the <cstdio> header where fprintf is defined: "The contents and meaning of the header <cstdio> are the same as the C standard library header <stdio.h>." C standard states "The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances: [...] The value of a pointer to a FILE object is used after the associated file is closed (7.21.3)." Therefore, calling fprintf on a closed file is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jacob UB is not mutually exclusive with everything appearing to work as expected with the exception of fprintf not writing that one line to the file. It *could* work exactly as expected, but it *could* also crash, write garbage to the file, go into an infinite loop, overflow your stack, or do anything. Moreover, the undefined-ness applies to the entire program, not just that line, so the compiler *could* decide to replace the function or even your whole program with return 0, or cause bugs which may be hard to debug as the bug may manifest somewhere unrelated to the code causing the UB.

Comment: @mCoding got it, thanks, do you think it's possible to check if `FILE*` is closed like we can do this for `std::fstream` when invoking `is_open()'`? I saw only people writing to manually close it and assign nullptr to our `FILE*`? So in this example I could only run `fprintf` when file is not closed.

Comment: @Jacob There is no way to check if a `FILE*` is open. You must keep track of it yourself, and this is exactly what the `shared_ptr` does for you.  The `shared_ptr` will call `fclose` when the reference count goes to 0, and calling fclose on an already closed file is UB. Therefore, if you used a `shared_ptr` to take ownership of an open file, you must not manually call fclose, you must let the shared_ptr do it in its destructor. A file will remain open unless closed, so there is no need to check if it is open. The file *is* open as long as a `shared_ptr` keeping a reference to it is alive.